Nullable reference type not working without an intermediate variable
I have this code and I don't understand why the last line gives me a warning if the previous two don't:
    [return: NotNull]
    public static IEnumerable<T> EmptyIfNull<T>(this IEnumerable<T>? sourceEnumerable) => sourceEnumerable ?? Array.Empty<T>();

    public static void ConfigurationSectionTest(IConfigurationSection? cfg)
    {
        IEnumerable<IConfigurationSection>? myChildren = cfg?.GetChildren();
        IEnumerable<IConfigurationSection> safeChildren = myChildren.EmptyIfNull();
        IEnumerable<IConfigurationSection> safeChildren2 = cfg?.GetChildren().EmptyIfNull(); //Warning: Converting null literal or possible null value to non-nullable type.
    }


What if cfg is null? Try IEnumerable<IConfigurationSection> safeChildren2 = cfg?.GetChildren().EmptyIfNull() ?? Array.Empty<IConfigurationSection>();

@Fildor then myChildren is null, then EmptyIfNull returns an IEnumerable<> pointing to an empty array, right?
Edit in response to your edit: EmptyIfNull already does that.

No. EmptyIfNull will not be executed in that case.

@Fildor Why would it not?

Because GetChildren wouldn't be executed. It only is if cfg is not null.

@Fildor I was udner the impression the ?. would make the result nullable and pass it to EmptyIfNull regardless of whether it called the member or method... is that not how ?. works?

No, it terminates the expression when null. If it didn't, then .GetChildren() would throw a NullReferenceException.

Not exactly. It is more equivalent to var result = (cfg is null)? null : cfg.GetChildren()

"A null-conditional operator applies a member access (?.) or element access (?[]) operation to its operand only if that operand evaluates to non-null; otherwise, it returns null" https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-

So it skips the entire expression, not just the member access?
I noticed the warning disappears if I add parentheses (cfg?.GetChildren()).EmptyIfNull();, what you say would explain this behavior.

The quote doesn't mention that the code following the member access is skipped too... But the linked page does.
Edit: This might be a better quote: The null-conditional operators are short-circuiting. That is, if one operation in a chain of conditional member or element access operations returns null, the rest of the chain doesn't execute.

Looking at what happened behind this may help you understand: https://shorturl.at/cewO4

"The code following the member access" is "belonging" to the member access, so to speak. (Yeah now crucify me. I tried to express it in a colloquial term.)

Related/Possible duplicate?

@Fildor this is the part I had failed to grasp. You may make this an answer...

While the answers are correct, I would suggest a slightly different approach to solve this: I'd do an extension on IConfigurationSection? like public static IEnumerable<IConfigurationSection> GetChildrenOrDefault( this IConfigurationSection? cfg ) => (cfg?.GetChildren()) ?? Array.Empty<IConfigurationSection>();

Check out the docs for the Null-conditional operators ?. and ?[]
:

The null-conditional operators are short-circuiting. That is, if one operation in a chain of conditional member or element access operations returns null, the rest of the chain doesn't execute. In the following example, B isn't evaluated if A evaluates to null and C isn't evaluated if A or B evaluates to null:
A?.B?.Do(C);
A?.B?[C];


Hence the cfg?.GetChildren().EmptyIfNull(); is null if cfg is null.
One workaround is to use parenthesis:
// no warning
IEnumerable<IConfigurationSection> safeChildren2 = (cfg?.GetChildren()).EmptyIfNull();


What a counter-intuitive design decision.

@Medinoc It's widely used, and always behaves in a short-circuiting manner: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elvis_operator#Languages_supporting_the_Elvis_operator.

The use of EmptyIfNull() is making it seem counter intuitive. Generally the expression would be followed by ?? (null-coalescing operator), which serves as a catch all, if any part of the expression is null.

@Medinoc while I can totally see your point, there are strong reasons why this work as is (hence you will get NRE if it wouldn't).

This:
cfg?.GetChildren().EmptyIfNull();

is equivalent to
cfg is null ? null : cfg.GetChildren().EmptyIfNull();

You can take advantage of brackets though:
(cfg?.GetChildren()).EmptyIfNull();

which translates to
(cfg is null ? null : cfg.GetChildren()).EmptyIfNull();

